An upper bound for advantage in a security game

Suppose I have defined a security game in a private-key (symmetric) encryption scheme.
Remark: Note that encryption algorithm is probabilistic, so for a specific message m, $Enc_k(m)$ might output a different ciphertext when
runs multiple times, which means that $Enc_k(m)$ is a random variable over ciphertext
space C with probability function $P_m$.
Now I try to rewrite advantage as :
$$
\begin{align}
\mathsf{Adv}&=\frac{1}{2}|P(b^{'}=1\mid b=1)-P(b^{'}=1\mid b=0)|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}|P[D(Enc_k(m_1))=1]-P[D(Enc_k(m_0))=1]|  
\end{align}
$$
where $D(Enc_k(m_i))=1$ means that adversary's distinguisher output $b^{'}=1$ when he receives the ciphertext $Enc_k(m_i)$.
From Remark above, we know that there exists two probability distributions $P_{m_0}$ and $P_{m_1}$ represent $Enc_k(m_0)$ and $Enc_k(m_1)$.
My conclusion now is to prove that $\mathsf{Adv}\leq\frac{1}{2}TVD(P_{m_1},P_{m_0})$, or more precisely, find the relationship between them.
What I have done is, we can split adversary's ability into two cases :

assume adversary is deterministic
assume adversary is probabilistic

I hope someone can point out whether my conclusion is true or not, if true, how can we prove that?

A few comments.

which means that $\mathsf{Enc}_k(m)$ is a random variable over ciphertext space $C$ with probability function $P_m$

This is maybe true in some special cases, but is the wrong way to think about things. In particular, this is true if an adversary may only submit one encryption query. But if they may submit two encryption queries, it might make you think that the relevant distribution on pairs of ciphertexts $C^2$ is something like $P_m\times P_m$, the "product distribution". This is wrong, the second message may adaptively be chosen dependent on the first ciphertext.
That being said, your overall idea is right. In particular, for an adversary $A$, you might write $A_b$ for the quantity $\Pr[A\text{ outputs }1\text{ in game } b]$.
Note that $A$'s output is in $\{0,1\}$, so $A_b\in[0,1]$ actually completely describes the output probability distribution of $A$ (any distribution on $\{0,1\}$ is Bernoulli, completely described by a single real parameter).
You can then write the distinguishing advantage as the total variation distance between $\mathsf{Bern}(A_0)$ and $\mathsf{Bern}(A_1)$, as you want to do.
As for the distinction between randomized/deterministic adversaries, it doesn't end up mattering here. This is well-known and easy to prove, but I'll furnish a proof regardless.
Any randomized adversary $A(x)$ may be viewed as a deterministic adversary $A(x;r)$, who additionally takes as input random coins $r$.
I'll write $A^r(x) = A(x;r)$ to be the deterministic adversary obtained by fixing random coins $r$.
Any such choice of random coins $r$ may yield different output distributions $A^r_b$.
The question is then how is the advantage of $A$ related to something like $\mathsf{TV}(\mathsf{Bern}(A^r_0), \mathsf{Bern}(A^r_1))$? Which $r$ should be chosen on the right? Or should we "average" over $r$?
One has that
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Adv}_A &= \frac{1}{2}|\Pr[b' = 1\mid b = 1] - \Pr[b' = 1\mid b = 0]|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}|\Pr[\mathsf{Bern}(A_1) = 1] - \Pr[\mathsf{Bern}(A_0) = 1]|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}|\mathbb{E}_r[\Pr[\mathsf{Bern}(A_1^r) = 1] - \Pr[\mathsf{Bern}(A_0^r) = 1]]|\\
& \leq \mathbb{E}_r[\frac{1}{2}|\Pr[\mathsf{Bern}(A_0^r) = 1] - \Pr[\mathsf{Bern}(A_1^r) = 1]|]\\
& = \mathbb{E}_r[\mathsf{TV}(\mathsf{Bern}(A_0^r), \mathsf{Bern}(A_1^r)]\\
&\leq \sup_r \mathsf{TV}(\mathsf{Bern}(A_0^r), \mathsf{Bern}(A_1^r)).
\end{align*}
This is to say that because of the triangle inequality, we can upper bound the advantage of $A$ by the expected advantage of $A_r$. We can then take the supremum over $r$ to say that for any randomized $A$, there is (at least) one choice of randomness $r$ such that $A^r$ has at least as high advantage as $A$. So you can start by analyzing general, randomized $A$, and quickly show that restricting to analyzing deterministic $A$ loses no generality.

This answer helps me a lot to simplify my calculation, but moreover, does it mean that we can always assume our adversary to be deterministic?

@EddyLiu It depends. If we don't consider running time, the optimal adversary is always deterministic, as the above shows. The issue is finding the optimal random string $r$ may be computationally expensive. In real life though, an adversary who uses a sufficiently good PRG to generate $r$ should have indistinguishable outputs from a randomized adversary (if they don't, they break the security of the PRG), so practically you can always assume deterministic adversaries, provided you assume you have a secure PRG as well.
